# ToolkitExpander must expand slowly in windows phone8

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a toolkit expander control in windows phone 8 it is working fine  .I have to expand the items slowly.and collapse them slowly.What additionally i have to add to expand and collapse slowly

```
       <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="Header1" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" Expanded="Header1_Expanded">
                <toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
                    <Grid x:Name="GettinghereGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" >
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Menu/getting-here.png" Margin="8,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="None"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Getting here &amp; around" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" FontSize="26" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle Height="2" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#D6D6D6D6" Width="500" />
                    </Grid>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
                <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="Gettingherebutton" Margin="-230,1,0,0" Background="#EBEBEB" Click="Gettingherebutton_Click" >
                        <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#EBEBEB">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Getting here" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10" FontSize="26" Foreground="#9DA1A9" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Template>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                    <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="#D6D6D6D6" Width="500" Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="Gettingaroundbutton" Margin="-230,0,0,0" Background="#EBEBEB"  Foreground="#9DA1A9" Click="Gettingaroundbutton_Click">
                        <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#EBEBEB">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Getting around" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10" FontSize="26" Foreground="#9DA1A9" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Template>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                    <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="#D6D6D6D6" Width="500" Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="Factsbutton" Margin="-230,0,0,0" Background="#EBEBEB"  Foreground="#9DA1A9" Click="Factsbutton_Click_1">
                        <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#EBEBEB">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Facts &amp; essenial info" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10" FontSize="26" Foreground="#9DA1A9" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Template>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                    <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="#D6D6D6D6" Width="500" Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="Adayoutbutton" Margin="-230,0,0,0" Background="#EBEBEB"  Foreground="#9DA1A9" Click="Adayoutbutton_Click">
                        <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#EBEBEB">
                                    <TextBlock Text="A day out" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10" FontSize="26" Foreground="#9DA1A9" FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomLucidaGrandStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Template>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                    <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="#D6D6D6D6" Width="500" Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Collapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-35"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expandable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Line">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Expander" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <!--<Line x:Name="Line" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1"/>-->
                        <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,0,0,0" Opacity="0.0" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of trial and error i got this
By changing the keytime of easout function we are going to expand it @ what we need similarly in easin  function if we change it collapses slowly

```
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.95" Value="1"/>
```